# In React is there a way to remount a component with a button click from another component?

Tags: reactjs

Upon button click, I'm passing props from a parent to a child component. The child component is then supposed to make API calls according to the props the parent component passes but the child only renders once (upon mounting). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add some code so we can get a full understanding of your problem 

Comment: [mcve] are indeed useful but I don't think, in this case, there is much need for it! React users can understand what the OP is talking about.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot make the call in the parent and then pass the result as props to the child?

Answer (score 3):

You could add the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook and check if the props have changed and create another API call that way, or you can set a new `key` prop on the child component from the parent in order to unmount the previous one and mount a new one.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    childKey: Math.random()
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ childKey: Math.random() });
  };

  render() {
    const { childKey } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Remount Child</button>
        <Child key={childKey} prop={childKey} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    data: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ data: this.props.prop, isLoading: false });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, data } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return <div>{data}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```